# Firebase database shows nothing when I sent an image to a user. reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
package com.xiong.c2chat2021;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Adapter.MessageAdapter;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Fragments.APIService;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Model.Chat;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Model.Chatlist;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Model.User;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Notifications.Client;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Notifications.Data;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Notifications.MyResponse;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Notifications.Sender;
import com.xiong.c2chat2021.Notifications.Token;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  CircleImageView profile_image;
  TextView username;

  FirebaseUser fuser;
  DatabaseReference reference;

  ImageButton btn_send, sent_image_btn;
  EditText text_send;

  MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
  List<Chat> mchat;

  RecyclerView recyclerView;

  Intent intent;

  ValueEventListener seenListener;

  String userid;

  APIService apiService;

  private String checker = "",myUrl="";
  private Uri fileUri;
  private StorageTask uploadTask;
  private String sender,  receiver, message;
  private static final int IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;

  boolean notify = false;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);

      Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              // and this
              startActivity(new Intent(MessageActivity.this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
          }
      });

      apiService = Client.getClient("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").create(APIService.class);

      recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
      recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
      linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

      profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
      username = findViewById(R.id.username);
      btn_send = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
      text_send = findViewById(R.id.text_send);

      //sent_image_btn
      sent_image_btn = findViewById(R.id.sent_image_btn);

      intent = getIntent();
      userid = intent.getStringExtra("userid");
      fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

      btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              notify = true;
              String msg = text_send.getText().toString();
              if (!msg.equals("")) {
                  sendMessage(fuser.getUid(), userid, msg);
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "You can't send empty message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              text_send.setText("");
          }
      });

      //image sending
      sent_image_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              notify = true;
                  openImage();

          }
      });



      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
              username.setText(user.getUsername());
              if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
                  profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
              } else {
                  //and this
                  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
              }

              readMesagges(fuser.getUid(), userid, user.getImageURL());
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });

      seenMessage(userid);
  }

  private void openImage() {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setType("image/*");
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      startActivityForResult(intent,IMAGE_REQUEST);
  }

// image_sending_activity

  private void uploadImage() {


      StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Image Send File");

              /*
              String messageSenderRef = "Messages/" + userid + "/" + fuser.getUid();
              String messageReceiverRef = "Messages/" + fuser.getUid() + "/" + userid;

              DatabaseReference userMessageKeyRef = reference.child("Messages")
                      .child(fuser.getUid()).child(userid).push();

              String messagePushID = userMessageKeyRef.getKey();
              */

      StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + "jpg");

      uploadTask = filePath.putFile(fileUri);
      uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot,Task<Uri>>() {
          @Override
          public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws
                  Exception {
              if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                  throw task.getException();
              }
              return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
          }
      }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
              DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                  Uri downloadImageUri = task.getResult();
                  myUrl = downloadImageUri.toString();


                  HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                  hashMap.put("sender", fuser);
                  hashMap.put("receiver", userid);
                  hashMap.put("imagemessage", fileUri);
                  hashMap.put("isseen", false);


                  reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);


                  // add user to chat fragment
                  final DatabaseReference chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
                          .child(fuser.getUid())
                          .child(userid);

                  chatRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                          if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                              chatRef.child("id").setValue(userid);
                          }
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                      }
                  });

                  final DatabaseReference chatRefReceiver = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
                          .child(userid)
                          .child(fuser.getUid());
                  chatRefReceiver.child("id").setValue(fuser.getUid());

                  final String msg = message;

                  reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());
                  reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                          User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                          if (notify) {
                              sendNotifiaction(receiver, user.getUsername(), msg);
                          }
                          notify = false;
                      }

                      @Override
                      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                      }
                  });
              }

          }
      });
  }


  private void seenMessage(final String userid) {
      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
      seenListener = reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                  if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(userid)) {
                      HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                      hashMap.put("isseen", true);
                      snapshot.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                  }
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
  }

  private void sendMessage(String sender, final String receiver, String message) {

      DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

      HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
      hashMap.put("sender", sender);
      hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
      hashMap.put("message", message);
      hashMap.put("isseen", false);

      reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);


      // add user to chat fragment
      final DatabaseReference chatRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
              .child(fuser.getUid())
              .child(userid);

      chatRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                  chatRef.child("id").setValue(userid);
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });

      final DatabaseReference chatRefReceiver = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist")
              .child(userid)
              .child(fuser.getUid());
      chatRefReceiver.child("id").setValue(fuser.getUid());

      final String msg = message;

      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());
      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
              if (notify) {
                  sendNotifiaction(receiver, user.getUsername(), msg);
              }
              notify = false;
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
  }

  private void sendNotifiaction(String receiver, final String username, final String message) {
      DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
      Query query = tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(receiver);
      query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  Token token = snapshot.getValue(Token.class);
                  Data data = new Data(fuser.getUid(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher, username + ": " + message, "New Message",
                          userid);

                  Sender sender = new Sender(data, token.getToken());

                  apiService.sendNotification(sender)
                          .enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                              @Override
                              public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                                  if (response.code() == 200) {
                                      if (response.body().success != 1) {
                                          Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                      }
                                  }
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                              }
                          });
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
  }

  private void readMesagges(final String myid, final String userid, final String imageurl) {
      mchat = new ArrayList<>();

      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              mchat.clear();
              for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                  if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myid) && chat.getSender().equals(userid) ||
                          chat.getReceiver().equals(userid) && chat.getSender().equals(myid)) {
                      mchat.add(chat);
                  }

                  messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mchat, imageurl);
                  recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
  }

  private void currentUser(String userid) {
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
      editor.putString("currentuser", userid);
      editor.apply();
  }

  private void status(String status) {
      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());

      HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
      hashMap.put("status", status);

      reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      status("online");
      currentUser(userid);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      reference.removeEventListener(seenListener);
      status("offline");
      currentUser("none");
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
              && data != null && data.getData() != null){
          fileUri = data.getData();

          if (uploadTask != null && uploadTask.isInProgress()){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload in preogress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
              uploadImage();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here][1]

````
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:661)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:141)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159)
        at com.xiong.c2chat2021.MessageActivity$5.onComplete(MessageActivity.java:251)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6735)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:657)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:141) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:60) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159) 
        at com.xiong.c2chat2021.MessageActivity$5.onComplete(MessageActivity.java:251) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6735) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source:121)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:12)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:657) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:47) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:675) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:167) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(CustomClassMapper.java:141) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(CustomClassMapper.java:60) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(DatabaseReference.java:282) 
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:159) 
        at com.xiong.c2chat2021.MessageActivity$5.onComplete(MessageActivity.java:251) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6735) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
```[enter image description here][2]
````

I want to send images by using hashmap like the method of sending messages

```
package com.xiong.c2chat2021.Model;

public class Chat {

    private static String from;
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String message,type,imagemessage;
    private boolean isseen;

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message, boolean isseen) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.message = message;
        this.imagemessage =imagemessage;
        this.isseen = isseen;
        this.from = from;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Chat() {
    }

    public static String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isIsseen() {
        return isseen;
    }

    public void setIsseen(boolean isseen) {
        this.isseen = isseen;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getImagemessage() {
        return imagemessage;
    }

    public void setImagemessage(String imagemessage) {
        this.imagemessage = imagemessage;
    }


}
```

I run it finding the issue that located at com.xiong.c2chat2021.MessageActivity$5.onComplete(MessageActivity.java:251)
I tried to change it with different ways but the app was crash again and again.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMhQy.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxvE6.png
```

Comment: There's a lot of code in your question, with many calls to `setValue` (which is what the crash report is about. Which one is causing the crash? Can you reproduce the problem with a simpler program/less code? Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 650 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.